# SSHtools disable Verifying host key[Yes/No] message?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

Hi is there an easy way to disable this host verification in j2ssh (assigning yes somewhere) that every time I connect to server I shoudn't type Yes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SSH, there is a configuration option:

```
StrictHostKeyChecking=no
```

You can probably set this in `j2ssh` like this:

```
setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no")
```

Whether this is a good idea is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: @Johnsweb Well I use java and  ssh = new SshClient(); ssh.(methods doesnt have .setConfig(string?!,string);) now if this is a good idea? 2 options because im creating an application/exe thing if i use this verification user can login automatically; but otherwise security might be compromised :D

Comment: Well solved it but in a very strange an probably ineffective way aded a class from [here](http://angelborroy.wordpress.com/2008/07/28/ftps-in-java/) then ssh.connect("127.0.0.1", 22, new AlwaysAllowingConsoleKnownHostsKeyVerification());

Comment: @user615927: You're connecting via SSH to *localhost*?

Comment: @user615927: * Occasionally* I do things outside monitoring accepted answers on StackOverflow (in this case, sleep, since you ask)! A `new` [`com.sshtools.j2ssh.transport.IgnoreHostKeyVerification`](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/com/sshtools/j2ssh/transport/IgnoreHostKeyVerification.html) seems to be what you need to pass into `connect()`. I also recommend using a hostname (rather than IPv4) in your `SshConnectionProperties`.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to validate the host, the following piece of code should do the job:

```
ssh.connect(hostname, new IgnoreHostKeyVerification());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet, just replace the parts from the example [here](https://github.com/petergeneric/j2ssh/blob/master/examples/PasswordConnect.java).

```
  SshClient ssh = new SshClient();
  ssh.setSocketTimeout(30000);
  SshConnectionProperties props = new SshConnectionProperties();
  props.setHost(hostname);
  props.setPort(port);
  ssh.connect(props , new IgnoreHostKeyVerification()); // ignore unknown host warning
  // Create a password authentication instance
  PasswordAuthenticationClient pwd = new PasswordAuthenticationClient();
  pwd.setUsername(username);
  pwd.setPassword(password);     
  // Try the authentication
  int result = ssh.authenticate(pwd);
```